# O console não está respondendo a um evento que criei no javascript

Tags: javascript, html

O meu código não está respondendo de acordo com o que eu criei. Estou tentando captar um clique em cima de uma lista renderizada mas o `addEventListner` não está captando nada. A lista está sendo renderizada corretamente.

```js
 window.onload = function(){
    //your code here
    const ListaFrutas = [
        {
            'fruta':'Mamão',
            'Preço':3.9,
            'imagem':'1'
        },
        {
            'fruta':'Laranja',
            'Preço':0.7,
            'imagem':'2'
        },
    ]
    
    const frutas = document.getElementById('produtos')
    ListaFrutas.map((n) => {
        frutas.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', `<li class="listaDeFrutas"><img src="assets/img/${n.imagem}.jpg" alt="">${n.fruta}</li>`);
    })

    let frutasQuery = document.querySelector('#mostraTotalCompra');
    let hideClass = document.querySelector('.hide');

    frutasQuery.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        console.log('it works')
    })
    

  }
```

```html
<div id="content-produtos" class="flex" >
  <ul id="produtos" >
  </ul>
</div>

<h2>Sua Cesta</h2> 
<div id="content-lista-produtos-cliente" class="flex">

  <ul id="cestaDoCliente"></ul>

  <div id="content-totalCompras" class="flex flex-row-end">
    <span class="flex">
      TOTAL
    </span>
    <input type="type" id="mostraTotalCompra" name="" disabled>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: O `input` está `disabled` e por isso ele não aceita `click`

Answer (score 0):

O problema está apenas no seu `input`. No seu contexto em específico, o atributo `type` deveria receber `button` como valor. O atributo `name` é redundante para esse cenário, logo, podemos descartá-lo. Por fim, o atributo `disabled` faz com que o seu `input` fique desabilitado, não haverá nenhuma ação de clique perante esse elemento, e é justamente por conta disso que seu `addEventListener` não está funcionando como deveria. **OBS: o atributo `disabled` funciona mesmo não passando nenhum valor para ele, é como se seu valor fosse `verdadeiro` (desabilitado)**.

Siga as correções abaixo:

```
<input type="button" id="mostraTotalCompra">
```